# reduce file count on Shared Hosting package

Tags: wordpress, file, count

So I have a shared hosting package with 130 websites, mixed HTML and Wordpress.

Currently cannot make any updated due to me reaching my Max file quanity quota of 262,144.. got no warnings so now in a sticky situation..

Cant event delete a Wordpress plugin as no room to move.. So I started housekeeping and deleted load of stuff and freed up 5000 files..

But later I see they have disappeared.. Can anyone suggest a way forward.. ?

I could open a 2nd account and start moving the sites across but that will be a long painful process...

Answer (score 0):

Your options as I see it are,

1. Remove unneeded sites and WordPress plugins/themes. Sounds like you've already started on this. You might try removing plugins/themes via WP vs FTP your hosting providers file manager. Not sure if the results will vary.
2. Change some sites to be static files instead of WordPress sites. WordPress has a lot files…
3. Move sites to a different hosting account. This is going to be the only option that gives you any great amount of flexibility.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - seems my whole server has been hacked hence repeat file generation hence big headache for me and costs... love hackers